# Print a document with winapi

Tags: winapi, printing

I'm currently sending a document to default printer with shell execute in my program, i was wonder is there any winapi can directly send a file to given printer ?

Current code looks like ;

```
    SetDefaultPrinter((LPWSTR)"XXX Printer Name");
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shInfo = { 0 };
    shInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shInfo.lpFile = (LPCWSTR)"c:\\test.pdf"
    shInfo.lpVerb = (LPCWSTR)L"print";
    shInfo.dwHotKey = VK_SPACE;
    shInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;
    result = ShellExecuteEx(&shInfo);
```

Is there any alternatives ?

Comment: Why are you taking an ASCII string and hard-casting it to a Unicode string? That will never work.

Comment: There's also a "printto" verb, it might well be supported by your default PDF association.  Use lpParameters to pass the printer name.  Yes, get rid of those casts.

Comment: @RaymondChen; this is actually pseudo code. Whole hardcoded strings are comes from variables ...

Comment: @HansPassant; PDF was just an example i can print any kinds of file, i just wanna know if is there any other alternatives ?

Comment: Programs that handle printable documented generally also implement the "printto" verb.  Whether the programs that you have installed on your machine in fact do support it is unguessable from here.  Do ask specific questions at SO, avoid broken pseudo code and irrelevant examples.